# what is wrong with this template code in c++20

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2019, c++20, spaceship-operator

template problems; the first one is the header file contain the template and it definition, the visual studio 2019 show no warning with /C++lastest feature(c++20)

```
#ifndef PAIR_H
#define PAIR_H

#include <compare>
#include <iostream>

template <typename First, typename Second>
class Pair
{
public:
  // Public members + no m_ prefix analogous to std::pair<> (see <utility> module)
  First first;    
  Second second;

  Pair() = default;
  Pair(const First& f, const Second& s);
  
  // Note: not all compiler may fully support this generation yet (C++20)...
  // (replacing auto with std::strong_ordering may make Soln17_02.cpp compile then,
  // but in general auto is better because First and/or Second could be types 
  // that are not strongly ordered, such as a floating-point types)
  auto operator<=>(const Pair& other) const = default;
};

// Constructor
template <typename First, typename Second>
Pair<First, Second>::Pair(const First& f, const Second& s)
  : first{f}, second{s}
{}

template <typename First, typename Second>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Pair<First, Second>& pair)
{
  return out << '(' << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << ')';
}

#endif
```

and bellow is just on the solution

```
#include "Pair.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  // To make the s string literal suffix work 
  // (facilitates creation of Pairs using CTAD, or Constructor Template Argument Deduction).
  // This syntactic sugar for creating std::string objects is not really covered in the book.
  using namespace std::string_literals;

  auto my_pair{ Pair{122, "abc"s} };
  ++my_pair.first;
  std::cout << "my_pair equals " << my_pair << std::endl;

  auto pair1{ Pair{  0, "def"s} };
  auto pair2{ Pair{123, "abc"s} };
  auto pair3{ Pair{123, "def"s} };

  std::cout << (pair1 < pair2 && pair2 < pair3? "operator< seems to be working" : "oops") << std::endl;
  std::cout << (pair1 == pair2? "oops" : "operator== works as well") << std::endl;
}
```

i just can't compile and it show this "Error    C2098   unexpected token after data member '<=' " which it point to this line "auto operator<=>(const Pair& other) const = default;". I already read the cpp++ reference about the operation<<. Is it template wrong or the something wrong?. Thank you

Comment: Which version of VS is it? You need at least VS 2019 16.2 (compiler version 19.22).

Comment: Are you sure you are using `c++20`? The error function seems as if it does not recognise `<=>` as a valid operator

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm my VS2019 is 16.10.3 (dont know compiler version but it report the msvc version 142 ).

Comment: @Lala5th i wondering too, follow the C++20 about visual-studio on some website, l have set the project configuration to use the lastest feature. according to the c++ reference website it should work as it worked for the author of the book

Comment: Did you make sure you configured your settings for your currently selected build type? Have you configured the project for both debug and release? I assume you're running in `Debug` but have you configured the project settings for `Release` and not `Debug` by accident (I've done stuff like that before, super annoying). Or you may have configured the project settings for `x64` but have `x86` selected on the top tool bar

Comment: @anhphan Yeah, it is just weird that it does not work then. You can try
`#ifndef __cpp_impl_three_way_comparison`
`#error no three way comp`, to check wether it is actually the compiler not liking it or something else. You can also check for `c++20` with `#if __cplusplus == 202002L` or in this case probably would be more accurate to throw an error if this isn't the case (i.e. ` __cplusplus < 202002L`)

Comment: @WBuck just redone it; both debug and release. Have same result that it keep warning me about the <=> operator.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 16.9.4 (compiler version 19.28), compiling with `cl /std:c++latest` I get different errors. The first is `error C3779: 'Pair<int,std::string>::operator <=>': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined`.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue via the code you provided. I can compile and run the code successfully. I'm using visual studio 2019 16.10.3, compiling with `/std:c++ latest`

Comment: @Lala5th i found the problem, it is because there are another source file with same wrong class so the compiler actually look up for that class first. thank for your time

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm you should check on visual-studio about your 16.9 version ,it may be diffirent on the cplusplus reference

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT i found the problems, i doubt when i saw the error but with your information i check back the file in the explorer and found the problem. Thank you for your time